# jqgrid editurl : controller action parameters

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jqgrid

When I use editurl property in my jqgrid, the controller action gets called after I hit submit button on adding a new row. But how do I get all the grid rows there? Which parameter should I read from my controller action method in order to get the grid data?

Grid code:

```
$("#list1").jqGrid({
            url: '/CMS/GetCustomLanguageData',
---
---                
editurl: '/CMS/SaveCustomLanguageData'
---
```

Add new row code:

```
grid.jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false,addCaption: "Add Record",
    editCaption: "Edit Record",
    bSubmit: "Submit",
    bCancel: "Cancel",
    bClose: "Close",
    saveData: "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
    bYes : "Yes",
    bNo : "No"
});
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult SaveCustomLanguageData()
{
}
```

Comment: Could you include the column definition (`colModel`) in your question, then my answer could be more clear. Which type has id which you use (int or string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jqGrid send to the controller named parameters with the name as you defined in the 'name' property of the `colModel`. Additionally will be send `oper=add` and `id=_empty`. So your controller action can look like following

```
public JsonResult SaveCustomLanguageData (string id, string oper, MyObject item)
{
    // test id for "_empty" or oper for "add".
    // If so add the item and return the value of the new id
    // for example return Json ("123");
}
```

on the client side you should decode the JSON response for example with the following code

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
        return [true, "", jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText)];
    }
});
```