# How to jsonify "Add" post/parameters for jqGrid

Tags: web-services, json, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

This one's killing me. I've read through a lot of [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)'s comments, and through the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#adding_row), but I think I'm overlooking something ***really*** simple.

I have a jqGrid populated by calling a webmethod that returns JSON. We're good there. I'm using the Navigator for my "Add" button, and using `onSelectRow` w/ `jqGrid.editRow()` for my editing.

I get the dialog box when clicking the "Add" button, and can fill everything in. However, I get a `error Status: 'Internal Server Error'. Error code: 500` return message after clicking the Submit button. Using Firebug, the `Response` is `{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: FileType.","StackTrace":....`. and the `Post` is `FileType=3&ExportDate=12%2F29%2F2010&oper=add&id=_empty`.

Obviously, my post is not getting "jsonified". I have tried using `serializeEditData`, and `beforeSubmit` in an attempt to manually return `JSON.stringify(eparams);`, but nothing has worked. Please see my code below.

**Webmethod**

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Sub ModifyFileLog(ByVal FileType As String, _
  ByVal ExportDate As Nullable(Of Date), _
  ByVal oper As String, ByVal id As String)
    Try
        ' blah
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**JS - Globals**

```
jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
        type: "POST",
        mtype: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        serializeGridData: function(data) {
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        gridview: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc"
    },
    jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
        ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        recreateForm: true,
        serializeEditData: function(postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        }
    }
);
```

**JS - jqGrid**

```
var tblName = "tblFiles";
var pager1 = '#pagerFiles';
var grid = $("#" + tblName);
grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'WebService.asmx/GetFileLog',
    colNames: ['ID', 'File Type', 'Report Date', 'Export Date', 'EE Count'],
    ajaxGridOptions: {
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                ReceivedClientData(JSON.parse(getMain(data)).rows, grid);  // populates grid
                endGridRequest(tblName);    // hides the loading panel
            }
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus) {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert('An error has occured retrieving data!');
        }
    },
    editurl: "WebService.asmx/ModifyFileLog",
    serializeEditData: function(postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    recreateForm: true,
    pager: pager1,
    ...
}); // end .jqGrid()
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', pager1, { add: true, del: false, edit: true, view: false, refresh: true, search: false },
    {}, // use default settings for edit
    {
        //beforeSubmit: submitAddFileLog,
        closeAfterAdd: false,
        closeAfterEdit: true
    }, // use default settings for add
    {},  // delete instead that del:false we need this
    {multipleSearch: false }, // enable the advanced searching
    {closeOnEscape: true} /* allow the view dialog to be closed when user press ESC key*/
); // end grid/jqGrid('navGrid')
```

NOTE: I started out populating by using `$.ajax()` by way of `datatype: function(data)`, but thought I would return to the simplest example to get this to work. If you care to offer your thoughts on the advantages of using `$.ajax()` over simply using `grid.jqGrid({ url: blah });`, I'd love to learn more. Otherwise, please let me know if it would be more appropriate to post it as a separate question.

Also, please let me know if I'm just flat out doing this the wrong way. I'm not locked in to any one way of getting this done. I would prefer to be wrong and to learn how to do this the right way, than to be "right" in my own mind and continue to hack my way through it.

Any help, along w/ examples, would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your main problem is in **JS - Globals**. You use [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function in a wrong way. You should replace one call

```
jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
        // ...
    },
    jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
        // ...
    }
);
```

to two separate calls:

```
jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
        // ...
    }
);
jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
        // ...
    }
);
```

After that the edit request to the server will be `{"FileType":3,"ExportDate"="12/29/2010","oper":"add","id":"_empty"}` instead of `FileType=3&ExportDate=12%2F29%2F2010&oper=add&id=_empty`.

Next, I am not sure that you can use `ExportDate` as a `Date` (`DateTime` ???) type. Probably you should start with `String` type and then convert the input data to the datatype which you need.

Next remark. Be sure that `ModifyFileLog` return JSON data. For example you can use `<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Xml)>` instead of `<ScriptMethod()>`. If you use .NET 4.0 you can achieve the same in many other ways.

One more thing. The `ModifyFileLog` should be `Function` instead of `Sub` and return the `Id` of new added object.  In case of edit or del operations the return value will be ignored.

Because `ModifyFileLog` `Function` will be returned JSON data you have to decode/parse it. You can do this almost in the same way which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076834/jqgrid-editurl-controller-action-parameters/4077902#4077902). In case of ASMX web service you can do about following:

```
jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
        ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        recreateForm: true,
        serializeEditData: function(postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
            var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            return [true, "", res.d];
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: is my hero, like he has been for so many other questions; thanks, Oleg. I have a follow-up question to one of your comments ( please let me know if I should start another question). 1) Would I need to use ResponseFormat.Json if I return a JSON object (using NewtonSoft)? 2) Would I need to run afterSubmit if I have reloadAfterSubmit: true? Also, using VB.NET 2.0, my function accepted ExportDate as Nullable(Of DateTime).

Comment: @mmengel: You welcome! I am glad to here, that I could help you. About your questions. 1) If you use `Json.NET` library of Newtonsoft you can better use WCF as ASMX web services (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118504/how-to-set-json-net-as-the-default-serializer-for-wcf-rest-service/3131413#3131413 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078397/returning-raw-json-string-in-wcf/3079326#3079326). In WCF you can declare method which retutn `Stream` and return **any** data type with custom serializer, so you can any use NewtonSoft instead of standard `ResponseFormat.Json`.

Comment: @mmengel: `afterSubmit` and `reloadAfterSubmit:true` do absolutely different things. If you can not return `Id` of the new row you **must** use `reloadAfterSubmit:true` of cause. If you have many sorted and paged items and you want to see new added item in the correct sorted order, you should use `reloadAfterSubmit:true`. In other situations `reloadAfterSubmit:false` can be OK. The user see the item which he just added and he like it. I prefer return new Id and use `afterSubmit` if needed always to be conform to jqGrid interface and be more sure that in new jqGrid version my program works OK.

Comment: @mmengel: If usage of `ExportDate` as `Nullable(Of DateTime)` work fine in case of your locale than you can use it of cause. I don't reproduced your program and was not sure that all will work. I personally prefer to use language independent formats for the data transfer, but it is not mandatory in real world.